# QGIS Cloud shape upload runtime error

Tags: qgis, cloud-gis

Using QGIS 2.12, Qgiscloud version 1.1.14 (on OSX 10.11). When uploading a shape (with 427 lines), I get this error:

```
Aanmaken van velden mislukt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/joris/.qgis2/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudplugindialog.py", line 729, in upload_data
    self.db_connections.db(db_name), data_sources_items, maxSize)
  File "/Users/joris/.qgis2/python/plugins/qgiscloud/data_upload.py", line 238, in upload
    raise RuntimeError(messages)
RuntimeError: Aanmaken van velden mislukt
```

How to solve this?